# How Can I track sender's country after a cllient submits form via contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there any mail-tags to use?
for instance; for tracking client's ip we can use; [_remote_ip]

Answer (score 0):

First step is to create an API key. To get an API key we have to register in the site [IPInfoDB.](http://ipinfodb.com/register.php)

Once API key is ready we have to download the file ip2locationlite.class.php from the site [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php).

Next step is to create our custom plugin.I named it as "country_custom_plugin.php". Its always good to create a custom plugin inside a folder, so that all the required files for the corresponding plugin stays in the folder. Named the folder as "country_custom_plugin"

Move the file "ip2locationlite.class.php" to the folder "country_custom_plugin".

/*Calling the function from contact-form-7 module and passing the result of the function stylus_ip_location_get_cc */

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'country_custom_ip_location', 10, 2 );

/*Function to get location of an user from the ip address*/

function country_custom_ip_location( $output, $name ){
  /*including the third party integration to get IP Location*/
  include_once('ip2locationlite.class.php');

  /*Special tag values are passed in format wpcf7.$name which we convert to _$name*/
  $name = preg_replace( '/^wpcf7\./', '_', $name );

  /*If location is requested in contact form enter the loop*/
  if ( '_custom_ip_location' == $name ) {
    $ipLite = new ip2location_lite;

    /*Entering the API key value generated*/
    $ipLite->setKey('"Enter your API Key Here"');

    /*Getting the IP address*/
      $ipaddress = preg_replace( '/[^0-9a-f.:, ]/', '', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

    /*Getting the Location*/
    $visitorGeolocation = $ipLite->getCity($ipaddress);

    if (!empty($visitorGeolocation) && is_array($visitorGeolocation)) {
       $output = $visitorGeolocation['regionName'] . ', ' . $visitorGeolocation['countryName'] . ', ' . $visitorGeolocation['countryCode'];
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

[Reference](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4124/how-to-display-location-of-an-user-in-a-mail-send-using-contact-form-7-plugin-by-passing-the-ip-address-in-a-wordp).Hope this will help. Please let me know if any issue.